# White lies are acceptable - Heinlein juvenile?

Tags: story-identification

I recall reading a Science Fiction tale as a child which had a profound effect on me.  In it the main character is told that we have to be able to tell certain lies.  No one should tell the truth under every circumstance.  What is the title of this work? I want to say it was by Heinlein but can't be certain.  I recall that the main character is told how he shouldn't really tell his Granny or Great Aunt what he really thinks of her hat and by extension how society couldn't function if we didn't tell certain lies.  I also have the suspicion that there was time travel involved.  I know I read the book in the 70's but figure it was published in the 50's-60's.

Comment: I think this is probably going to need more details.  Can you tell us anything about the characters?  Is the protagonist male? Female? Adult? Child?  When did you read this (what year, roughly)? Where did the story take place (on a planet, in space, in our universe, etc.)?

Comment: It could well a Heinlein book, because this theme of the need for white lies seems to come up a few times, but I can't guess which book from your description. There's a discussion of lying between a girl and her father in *To Sail Beyond the Sunset*, but it came out in 1988 so it's not the book you're thinking of.

Comment: Suggested duplicate target is much newer but has plot details more likely to be relevant to searchers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After searching in Google books on "white lies" and Heinlein, I found the following quote from [*The Door Into Summer*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Door_into_Summer) which is definitely what I had in mind.:

> She says people have to tell little white fibs or else people couldn't stand each other. But she says fibs were meant to be  used, not abused.

The idea that people couldn't stand each other without white lies is what really popped for me.  Now that I've read the summary I'll probably track it down even though John W. Campbell had this to say: “Bob can write a better story, with one hand tied behind him, than most people in the field can do with both hands. But Jesus, I wish that son of a gun would take that other hand out of his pocket.”

Comment: _The Door Into Summer_ is one of my favorite Heinlein books.

Comment: Eyeh, given how the love interest works out in that book, the line about one hand in the pocket is a but apt.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's quite what you're looking for, but [Time Enough for Love](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Enough_for_Love) includes a discussion of the two artistic ways of lying (telling part of the truth and telling the whole truth in a way that you aren't believed.)

Comment: You're almost certainly right that it's a Heinlein. In Job, the protagonist observes that the only injunction is not to "bear false witness against thy neighbour" - a specific and reprehensible act.  There is no prohibition of simple untruth". He adds that this is just as well given the likely consequences of telling a mother what you really think about her offspring.. Unfortunately Job is 1985 so too late to be the one you remember; but that is almost certainly an earlier Heinlein.